# Restrict access to few users instead of all users of a domain through winbind in Ubuntu

Tags: login

I've joined the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server into domain using winbind and smb. Able to retrieve the users details of users, groups etc successfully. The problem I do have is that all the users of a joined domain are able to login. But, I want to restrict the access to only few users instead of all users, something like for example, "which are specified in a file, namely pam_winbind.conf as in RHEL server" need to login, remaining users must not login. Please suggest.

Regards,
ABHILASH